# How can I combine duplicates in array into subarrays in this array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
['a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

I'd like to have:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['d'], ['f']]
```

Comment: First (and only) step: search for existing solutions.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const test = ["a", "b", "d", "a", "f", "b", "a", "b"]

function parseElements(elements) {
  const temp = {}
  for (const element of test) {
    if (!temp[element]) {
      temp[element] = []
    }
    temp[element].push(element)
  }

  return [...Object.values(temp)]
}

const result = parseElements(test)
```